# About a proof that $\lfloor x^2\rfloor = \lfloor x\rfloor^2$ for unbounded non integer values of $x$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am taking a first course in discrete mathematics. The instructor parsed the following question that has the following solution, respectively:

Prove the statement:

> For all positive integers $N$, there exists a real number $x$, so that $x$ is not an integer, $x>N$, and $\lfloor x^2\rfloor = \lfloor x\rfloor^2$.

[image: Solution]

Why is $x= N+ 1/(3N)$ used? I do not understand this statement. Is $1/(3N)$ some axiom of non-integer real numbers?

Also, what is the intuition behind squaring both sides at the end of the third line of the solution?

Comment: It's just a constructed choice to demonstrate the truth of the assertion.

Comment: We could also have chosen to use $x=N+\frac{1}{4N}$ or we could have chosen to use $x=\frac{1}{100N}$ or many other things.  It was used because it was convenient and because using $x=N+\frac{1}{2N}$ or $+\frac{1}{N}$ would not have worked for their argument.  $\frac{1}{3}$ is the next most convenient fraction after $\frac{1}{1}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ and happens to work.

Comment: As @Joffan said, this is nothing but an *educated guess* made by the author. Note that he couldn't have picked $1/2N$ because this bound wouldn't have been sharp enough for the square, but he could have picked any $1/kN, k\ge 3$ and the proof would have workes just as fine.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks. Can you check the edit?

Comment: Intuition? Check again what you have to prove, then it becomes quite clear...

Comment: @SajSeesSound Why did we square $\lfloor x\rfloor$?  Because that is precisely what the problem asks us to prove something about.  The problem asks us to show that for any given $N$, there exists an $x$ such that $N=\lfloor x\rfloor$ and that $\lfloor x^2\rfloor = \lfloor x\rfloor ^2$

Comment: There's a error(typo) in the stated solution, where it says "so $N$ is not an integer" it should of course say "so $x$ is not an integer". Not sure if that was confusing you at all.  There's an addition error further down, since actually $\frac 23 + \frac 19 = \frac 79$, not $\frac 59$. $\frac 79$ is still valid for the proof, though.  There's also a very minor glitch on the last line; it should show $N^2<x^2$, not $N^2\le x^2$. Which is not false, but seems a little slack.

Comment: @b00nheT: "Note that *he or she* couldn't have picked ... but *he or she* could have picked...."

Comment: Basically you want to show that $N <x <\sqrt {N^2+1} <N+1$ can be found for x. (That's just another way of stating the conditions).  If x=N+d we want 2Nd + d^2 < 1.  we could take a lot of effort to find the largest d just big enough...m or we could simply figure if d = 1/3N then 2Nd + d^2= 2/3 + 1/9N^2 < 2/3 + 1/9 <1 will do just fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you feel like numbers and expressions are appearing out of nowhere for no apparent reason,  it's because they are. It's part of the magic show of a completed proof to get a round of applause at the end when all the various pieces come together and fall neatly into place to produce the desired answer.

What the proof could have done to reduce the suspense but perhaps improve understanding is to tell you at the outset that the intention is to find a real $x$ for which $\lfloor x \rfloor =N$ and $\lfloor x^2\rfloor = N^2$, by making $x$ just a tiny fraction larger than $N$. The exploratory part - seeing just how tiny that fraction has to be - is left out of the proof; you just get to see the fruits of that investigation, a tiny but well-defined fraction that does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Since we want $x>N$, we can set $x=N+y$ with $y>0$. We also want
$$
\lfloor (N+y)^2\rfloor=\lfloor N+y\rfloor^2
$$
and, if we take $y<1$, the right-hand side is $N^2$. Thus we need
$$
(N+y)^2<N^2+1
$$
so that also the left-hand side is $N^2$. The inequality becomes
$$
y^2+2Ny-1<0
$$
that is satisfied by
$$
-N-\sqrt{N^2+1}<y<-N+\sqrt{N^2+1}
$$

It's not difficult to show that $\sqrt{N^2+1}-N<1$, so adding the above conditions $0<y<1$, we obtain the full set of solutions:
$$
0<y<\sqrt{N^2+1}-N
$$

---

The book chooses another way. The authors looked for a solution of the form $y=\frac{1}{aN}$, so they wanted
$$
N^2+\frac{2}{aN}+\frac{1}{a^2N^2}<N^2+1
$$
and this becomes
$$
\frac{2}{aN}+\frac{1}{a^2N^2}<1
$$
that can be rewritten as
$$
a^2N^2-2aN-1>0
$$
This is certainly satisfied for 
$$
a>\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{N}
$$
(just solve the quadratic). The maximum value of the bound for $a$ is when $N=1$, that is, $1+\sqrt{2}$ which is less than $3$. Then they could take $a=3$ and do the steps backwards in order to surprise the readers like when magicians pull a rabbit out of a top hat.